# insertBST exercise

Tags: beginner, haskell, tree, binary-search

I'm just learning Haskell on my own, and did an exercise to implement insertBST.

Is this idiomatic Haskell?

```
insertBST :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> a -> BST a -> BST a
insertBST _ v Leaf = Node Leaf v Leaf
insertBST cmp v (Node left nv right) = case (cmp v nv) of
        EQ -> Node (insertBST cmp v left) nv right
        LT -> Node (insertBST cmp v left) nv right
        GT -> Node left nv (insertBST cmp v right)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `EQ` and `LT` cases are the same, we can put `GT` first to remove this duplication

```
insertBST :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> a -> BST a -> BST a
insertBST _ v Leaf = Node Leaf v Leaf
insertBST cmp v (Node left nv right) = case cmp v nv of
        GT -> Node left nv (insertBST cmp v right)
        _  -> Node (insertBST cmp v left) nv right
```

If you install [hlint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint) you will also get warnings about things like the redundant parentheses that were around `cmp n nv`. You can set up your editor to run this automatically on save.